# Hyperledger composer rest server not responding after some idle time

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have a business network deployed on the composer with fabric docker containers running in docker swarm mode. composer rest server works fine and I can submit transactions and query through rest-server perfectly. But when server remains idle for some time without any transactions, if I send GET request, it fetches error `TCP read failed`, on the second attempt it returns `no response from server` and on the third try it shows the content correctly. If I POST after some time, then in peers' docker logs I can see transaction is happening and block gets added but in brower UI it is not reflected we can only see loading animation with no response at the rest server . Also at the peer logs I can see this error after trying to submit a transaction after some idle time `[endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 065 [composerchannel][48987feb] failed to invoke chaincode name:"supply-chain-network" , error: timeout expired while executing transaction` what is the issue here? Why it is working fine initially and after some time not properly getting the response?

Comment: How long is the idle time you refer to as "some time" ?  Can you describe your Fabric (peer/orgs) and what infrastructure does it run on?

Comment: Time is 15 mins. I'm running 2 peer 1 org network on docker swarm across two physical nodes. Peers are running on the same node while orderer is on the other node.

Comment: Did you resolved the issue ? if so, can you please post the answer ?

Comment: it was a docker swarm issue actually. I was running swarm overlay network in vip (virtual ip) model which only maintains the connection for 900 seconds and that's why the rest server wouldn't respond. I switched to dnsrr mode and the issue got solved. If you are using docker swarm check the overlay network documentation for more details.